# Does superclass constructor exist (but not inherited) in subclass?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, superclass

We are able to invoke super() from subclass constructor. Since subclass IS-A superclass , and there is only 1 object created ( new Subclass()) does this imply superclass constructor exists, although it cannot be inherited, in subclass?

Comment: Constructors are **never** inherited.

Answer (score 0):

[Constructors are not inherited](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8). Superclass constructor 'exists' in a way that you could call it from a subclass unless it's marked as `private`.

And as I.K. has mentioned class could have a [default constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9):

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default
>   constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is
>   implicitly declared.